# How can i fix the loading gif after the page is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want my gif animation to fade out after the page is fully loading. The gif still appears after loading right now. I tried some fadeOut javascript, but the whole page is faded out. If you can help, it'll be really appreciated, Here's my code.

```js
var $body = $('.loading');

var loading = [{
    elements: $body,
    properties: {
      width: '3%'
    }
  },
  {
    elements: $body,
    properties: {
      width: '60%'
    }
  },
  {
    elements: $body,
    properties: {
      width: '90%'
    }
  },
  {
    elements: $body,
    properties: {
      width: '100%'
    }
  },
  {
    elements: $body,
    properties: {
      height: '1260px'
    },
    options: {
      complete: function() {
        $('.wrap').velocity('transition.slideLeftIn');
        $('html').css({
          background: 'white'
        });
      }
    }
  }
];

$.Velocity.RunSequence(loading);
```

```css
<style>.loading {
  background: url("../img/icon.gif");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.wrap {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: none;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loading">
  <div class="wrap">contents</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Basith Thanks for your comments! i tried the code, but it didn't go through the page and kept loading. I also used used remove element to .loading, then the whole content is removed. Do you think is there any way targeted only background image fade out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fadeOut` jquery function, then remove or hide the element.

```
$('.wrap').fadeOut( 1000, function() {
    $('.wrap').remove();
});
```

Implementation in your code:

```
var loading = [
    { elements: $body, properties: { width: '3%' } },
    { elements: $body, properties: { width: '60%' } },
    { elements: $body, properties: { width: '90%' } },
    { elements: $body, properties: { width: '100%' } },
    { elements: $body, properties: { height: '1260px' }, options: { 
      complete: function () { 
        $('.wrap').fadeOut( 1000, function() {
           $('.wrap').remove();
        });
      }
    }
  }
];
```

Then call the function after the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.Velocity.RunSequence(loading);
})
```

Comment: @user15232620 can you please post your full code.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working

```js
$('.loading').css('background', 'transparent');
```